# Change background color of a cell when another cell is filled in

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Let's say I have a Google Sheet where A1 needs to be filled green when B1 till B7 has been filled in with no matter what;
and A1 needs to be red when 1 or more cells from B1 till B7 are not filled in yet.

Would this be possible in Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: Is google spreadsheet a replacement for the all powerful MS Excel? I'm really surprised to see so many questions on google apps

Answer (score 1):

Fill A1 red (normal fill) and apply a Conditional formatting rule of *Custom formula is* :

```
=counta(B1:B7)=7
```

with green Background Colour and *Range:* A1